# grep + arrays + index

Tags: arrays, bash, grep, multi-index

First sorry for the title but i dont realy know how to explain, i'm not experimented and it's probably realy simple to solve...

So i got two arrays:

```
AR1=(c a b c c d)
AR2=(z y x w v u)
```

I have to grep thing in `AR1` for make an `AR3` (this part is ok) but How can i do for have or `AR4` or `AR4bis`

```
AR3=(c c c d)
```

what i'm looking for:

```
AR4=(z w v u)
AR4bis=(0 3 4 5)
```

thx..

Comment: `grep` is for searching files, not variables.

Comment: So `AR4` is the elements from `AR2` that are in the same postion as `AR1` elements that are in `AR3`? And `AR4bis` is their indexes?

Comment: yes its this @barmar sorry

Comment: Who is barman? I'm barmar. SO has automatic name completion, there's no excuse for typos like that.

Comment: Would you get the same result with `AR3=(c d)`? Or do you only get to match each item once? Are the elements of `AR3` in the same order as in `AR1`?

Comment: How are you making `AR3`? If you're looping over `AR1` to do that, you can access the corresponding elements of `AR2` at the same time, and fill in `AR4` and `AR4bis` then.

Comment: no, i need `AR3=(c c c d)'

Comment: @Barmar i'm making AR1 like this `AR1=$(echo -e "$reponse" | grep "xyz" | cut -d '"' -f 4); IFS=$'\n'; AR1=($AR1)`

Comment: My question is how you're creating `AR3`. When you do that, you can also get the indexes, which are `AR4bis`, and then you can use that to get `AR4` from `AR2`.

Comment: sorry it was AR3 `AR3=$(echo -e "$reponse" | grep "xyz" | cut -d '"' -f 4); IFS=$'\n'; AR3=($AR1)` how can i get the indexex for store then in new array ? @barmar

Comment: Please, read [this guide](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)